# How to INDEX MATCH based on a MAX value and returning a cell next to the MAX

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, max, match

I have a table with product name, quantity1, quantity2, price.  If a product has a Quantity1 value >0 it have a Quantity2 value of 0 and vica versa.  I want to write a formula to return the product name with the highest list price if it has a number >0 in quantity1.

An example table is:

```
Product Name__     Quantity1__     Quantity2__     Price  
ProdA_____________5_________0______300  
ProdB_____________0________10______400  
ProdC_____________0_________7_____1000  
ProdD_____________5_________0_____1000
```

I attempted an `INDEX MATCH` that leveraged an `IF` statement and a `MAX` statement.

```
=INDEX(Product Name Range,MATCH(MAX(IF(Quantity1 Range>0,Price Range)),Price Range,0))
```

The problem is that the `INDEX MATCH` will pull the first product with the same list price identified with the `MAX` statement, resulting in incorrect results.  This formula in the example table above would pull ProdC incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=INDEX(ProductNameRange,MATCH(MAX(INDEX((Quantity1Range>0)*PriceRange,)),INDEX((Quantity1Range>0)*PriceRange,),0))
```

Comment: This is a nice formula! I did notice that if all of Quantity 1 is zero, this will still return Prod A. This is probably an unrealistic scenario, but just a thought.

Comment: @BigBen Yeah, could add a check for that.  wrap formula in `IF(COUNTIF(Quantity1Range,">0")=0,"",<formula>)`